# Docker API v2: call up list of both repos/images and their available tags in one call?

Tags: docker, command-line, repository

We have Docker API v2 on our internal system.  While I can call up the repositories with this:

```
https://docker.ourdomain.com/v2/_catalog
```

but I don't see a unified way to call up both the images (repositories) **and** the available tags, which for our use would be far more useful.  Instead, AFAIK, you have to form another query on a named repo/image, adding *image/tags/list*.

I don't understand why there isn't a central API call that shows both elements, as it would be very useful.

Is there a way to accomplish what I need?

Looked up the documentation along with examples available online, each with the same issue.